# Using GLFW3 with MinGW on Windows 8 (64 bit)

Tags: c++

code:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main() {
    if(glfwInit()) {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have the libraries linked (dll and .a files in MinGW lib). I have the include headers in MinGW/include/GLFW. This is the compiler (eclipse console) output:

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -o Test.exe "src\\Test.o" -lopengl32 -lglfw3
src\Test.o: In function 'main':
c:\Users\Bobby\Workspace\Test\Debug/../src/Test.cpp:11: undefined reference to 'glfwInit'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried many many things before posting here.

Comment: Try `-lglew32 -lgdi32 -lglu32`

Comment: Didn't work. I think that's one I tried before also.

Comment: Did you specify the library path?

Comment: It's able to link those libraries. I assume that's what you meant?

Comment: Are you sure it's able to link the libraries?

Comment: It doesn't give any errors. And I always get errors if I don't make my links right. I've been trying to get this to work for 3 days.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I downloaded the latest 32-bit version of GLFW3 for Windows, unpacked it in it's own directory (not the MinGW directory) compiled and linked your example program, and I don't get the undefined reference to `glfwInit`. I do get another error unfortunately though that indicates that the 32-bit static library isn't compatible with MinGW and requires the 32-bit version of MinGW-w64. However, the 32-bit import library (`glfw3dll.a`) seems to work OK with MinGW.

Comment: Yeah that error prints about 15 times? That error is before the glfwInit undefined reference error. So you have to fix that with 64 bit version before you get my error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a 32-bit compiler (either MinGW or the 32-bit version of MinGW-w64), make sure you downloaded the 32-bit version of GLFW3 for Windows and are using the files from the `lib-mingw` subdirectory. The 64-bit version of GLFW3 will only work with the 64-bit version of MinGW-w64, which is a separate project from the 32-bit only MinGW.

Note that the fact that you're using a 64-bit operating system doesn't matter. If you're using a 32-bit compiler then you need the 32-bit libraries.

While it's not the problem you've run into, I should also note here that 32-bit version GLFW3 for Windows isn't fully compatible with MinGW. The static library `lib-mingw/libglfw3.a` has a dependency on the MinGW-w64 runtime so won't link properly with MinGW. The import library `lib-mingw/glfw3dll.a` along with its associated DLL `lib-mingw/glfw3.dll`, should work fine with MinGW however.

Comment: I've tried both on both sides. Tried both Glfw3 64 bit and glfw3 32 bit. And did get the library from the lib-mingw directory.